# Change a method to private and use another overloaded version instead

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Code:

```
object Integral {
  def approx(start: Double, end: Double, nIntervals: Int)(f: Double => Double): Double = {
    val delta = (end - start) / nIntervals
    val halfDelta = delta / 2
    val xs = start until end by delta
    xs.map(x => f(x + halfDelta) * delta).sum
  }
  def approx(startEnd: Array[Double], nIntervas: Int)(f: Double => Double): Double = {
    require(startEnd.length == 2)
    val startEndSorted = startEnd.sorted
    val res = approx(startEndSorted(0), startEndSorted(1), nIntervas)(f)
    if(startEndSorted == startEnd) res else (-res)
  }
}

object IntegralTest {

  def f1(x: Double) = {
    math.pow(x, 3) - 6 * x
  }
  println(Integral.approx(0, 3, 6)(f1))
  println(Integral.approx(0, 1, 60000)(f1))

  def f2(x: Double) = {
    math.sqrt(1 - x * x)
  }
  println(Integral.approx(0, 1, 60000)(f2))
  println(math.Pi / 4)

  println(Integral.approx(0, 3, 60000)({
      (x: Double) => x - 1
    }))

  println(Integral.approx(1, 2, 5)({
    (x: Double) =>  1 / x
  }))

  // test the exponential function
  println(Integral.approx(1, 3, 60000)(math.exp))
  println(math.exp(3) - math.exp(1))

}
```

I want to make `approx(start: Double, end: Double, nIntervals: Int)(f: Double => Double): Double` private and change all the reference to it to `approx(startEnd: Array[Double], nIntervas: Int)(f: Double => Double): Double`, is there a way to do this safely and hassle-free in intellij?

---

#### Update

I soon realized that for this specific case I could have handled it in a better way (by recursion):

```
 def approx(start: Double, end: Double, nIntervals: Int)(f: Double => Double): Double = {
    if(start > end) {
      -approx(end, start, nIntervals)(f)
    } else {
      val delta = (end - start) / nIntervals
      val halfDelta = delta / 2
      val xs = start until end by delta
      xs.map(x => f(x + halfDelta) * delta).sum
    }
  }
```

But I am still interested in finding out how to refactor the old problematic code because it might be useful in the future.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using an `Array[Double]` as the public interface for providing the start and end, even though the client is required to provide exactly two values? This isn't typesafe - if at all possible it would be better to use separate `start: Double` and `end: Double` parameters for the public interface and then swap them behind the scenes if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if the fact you use it for Scala changes anything, but you should be able to right-click on a function, and [`Change method signature`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/change-method-signature-in-java.html) to the one you want (so you wouldn't replace function1 by function2 per se, but rather modify f1 to match f2).

Edit: This won't work as per Ben comment. Leaving anyway for the sake of mentioning the functionality.

Comment: This won't work - if you use `Change method signature` to remove the `start: Double` and `end: Double` arguments and replace them with `startEnd: Array[Double]`, a call to `approx(s, e, n)(f)` won't be successfully replaced with a call to `approx(Array(s, e), n)(f)` as the OP wants.